# WordPress plugin github-updater used with Bitbucket webhook

Tags: php, wordpress, git, bitbucket, webhooks

I am trying to use the API of the WordPress plugin github-updater to automate deployments by using a webhook at Bitbucket. When the webhook is triggered it calls the plugin's API through admin-ajax.php in the WordPress core on the production server.

When the Bitbucket webhook runs, it receives a 200 response from the production server so I know it is getting through, but there is nothing in the body of the response and there should be either a success message or an error message. Of course the git pull never happens either.

I'm unsure how to continue troubleshooting. The plugin's docs say there should be messages in the debug.log but there aren't. I am suspecting that admin-ajax.php is not even communicating with the API of the plugin but I'm not sure what steps to take to dig deeper.

Comment: Have you used their Slack channel?

Comment: I just found that, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the child theme had bugs in it that prevented Github Updater from working. Andy, the author of Github Updater was very nice about helping to troubleshoot.